# How to use Range.Find method for a merged cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the range.find method, but if the cell what i want to find is a merged cell the macro give me the **error 91**.

The function verifies if some text is in a worksheet, and return me an boolean while set a global range variable.

`wsDerecho` is a worksheet.

```
Public rngEncontrar As Range

Function Encontrar(ByVal Texto As String) As Boolean

    Set rngEncontrar = Nothing

    If Not wsDerecho.Cells.Find(Texto) Is Nothing And Texto <> "" Then
        Set rngEncontrar = wsDerecho.Cells.Find(What:=Texto, After:=wsDerecho.Range("A1"))
        Encontrar = True
    Else
        Encontrar = False
    End If

End Function
```

EDIT:

```
'Defined in another sub
Set wsDerecho = Workbooks.Open(RutaXLSX).ActiveSheet

Function GetNota()

    Dim PFila As Range

    Select Case strOrigen
        Case "Derechos SIC"
            Encontrar "NOTAS DEL EVENTO CORPORATIVO"
      'in this case the cell what i want to find return me false on Encontrar function because is merged.
        Case "Derechos BMV"
            Encontrar "AVISO A LOS ACCIONISTAS"
        Case "Derechos CCDS", "Derechos Fibras"
            Encontrar "AVISO A LOS TENEDORES"
    End Select

    Set PFila = rngEncontrar.Offset(1, 0) 
    'here i get back the error because didn't find the merged cell 
    GetNota = Concatenar(wsDerecho.Range(PFila, wsDerecho.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)))

End Function
```

I want to make the function could find and set the range even if the result is a merged cell.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share where you `Set wsDerecho`, as well as how you are calling `Encontrar`? Also, what line throws the error?

Comment: Your Function works on Merged and Non - Merged cells if I change `wsDerecho` with `Activesheet`. So there is something wrong the  way you are declaring thsi sheet

Comment: Your error 91 indicates that `wsDerecho` is set to `Nothing`. This means that when you tried to `Set wsDerecho = Workbooks.Open(RutaXLSX).ActiveSheet` this action failed because the other workbook doesn't exist. The error has nothing to do with merged cells.

Comment: Did you declare `wsDerecho` as Public ?

Comment: I don't have trouble declaring the worksheet, even i have to use the Encontrar function eight times before the merged cell with the same reference of wsDerecho without activate it.

Comment: I tried the     If Not wsDerecho.Cells.Find(Texto) Is Nothing And Texto <> "" Then with a non merged cell in this step and it work, is just with that value.

Comment: You never check whether `Encontrar` is successful in `GetNota`. That seems like an oversight.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `SeachFormat:=True`

> ```
> wsDerecho.Range(PFila, wsDerecho.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchFormat:=True)
> ```